# How to check if the following value contains one of the strings in the array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have an array

```
let items = ['hat', 'shirt', 'glasses', 'jeans']
```

`this.mainItem` is a property that has a value for sample 'black-hat'

How can I check if this.mainItem contains one of the strings in the array and if there is a mtach return that array item otherwise return '' empty string?

Comment: Please explain more properly

Comment: did you mean include ?

Comment: Yes but if it includes then it should return that array item

Comment: is black-hat and hat supposed to be considered as a match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `find` method:

```
items.find((item) => this.mainItem.includes(item)) || ""
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer will it return that array item?

Comment: Yes. The find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. More information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: The ` || ""` part will ensure that if no item is found empty string will be returned.

Comment: || part is not working it returns emty array instead of string

Comment: Here you have a working code: https://jsbin.com/tecorohuhi/edit?js,console,output.
It returns an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.filter()` function:

```
items.filter((item) => this.mainItem.includes(item))// will return Array [ "hat" ]
```

Comment: Then how to return empty string if it didn't find any value

Comment: it will return an empty array

Answer (score 0):

You can use the boolean:

```js
items.findIndex((el) => this.mainItem.includes(el)) !== -1
```

We use the new findIndex method and check if main tiem includes the element. If not, then the function returns -1